# Do there exist infinitely many languages that are RE-complete?

Tags: formal-languages, turing-machines

I would like to prove or disporove: there exists infinitely many languagess that are RE-Complete.

Here is my attempt of the proof.

Let $L$ be any RE-complete language. Define a padded version of $L$, denoted $L'$ as follows, where $k \in \mathbb{N}$ is a fixed number:
$$L' = \{x@^k \mid x \in L\}.$$
where $@$ is a new symbol not in the alphabet of $L$, and $k$ represents the number of times the symbol is repeated. The padded strings $x@^k$ are constructed in such a way that there is a one-to-one correspondence between the strings in $L$ and the strings in $L'$, preserving that $L'$ is recursively enumerable since we can enumerate $L$ and for each string in $L$, enumerate all its padded versions in $L'$.

Reduction from any RE language:
For any recursively enumerable language $A$, since L is RE-complete, there exists a computable reduction $f$ from $A$ to $L$. We can construct a reduction $f'$ from $A$ to $L'$ by composing $f$ with a padding function $g$, where $g(x)=x@^k$ for some fixed $k$. This shows that $L'$ is at least as hard as any RE-language.

Infinite Variants: By varying $k$, we can generate infinite distinct languages $L'_k = \{ x@^k \mid x \in L \}$, each of which is RE-complete by the argument above.

Comment: Are you trying to prove that there are infinitely many RE-complete languages, or are you trying to prove that there are infinite RE-complete languages?

Comment: english is my second language, can you explain the difference between the terms "infinitely many " and just " infinite " what did you mean?

Comment: The first refers to counting how many languages there are; the second refers to languages having infinitely many words in them.

Comment: I am referring to the first definition, first interpretation: there exists an infinite number of distinct RE-complete languages,

Comment: what do you think about my attempt? @Arno

Comment: I took the liberty to fix the English and LaTeX. I also modified the definition of $L'$ so that your answer reads correctly.

Comment: @AndrejBauer can you tell me if my attempt is correct? or should I fix it?

Comment: Assuming you are allowed to extend the alphabet, your attempt seems generally correct. We could discuss details and phrasing, but the main idea is ok. One improvement to try is to slove the problem without extending the alphabet?

Comment: If I can't extend the alphabet, how would I make a counter-example to contrast? @AndrejBauer

Comment: If you can figure that out by yourself, you will learn a lot. Keep in mind the following: you can computably encode $L$ into some other set $L'$ in any way you like, so long as you can also computable decode it in the reverse direction.

Comment: @AndrejBauer but I have no idea how to do it, can you give me a hint?

Comment: Suppose your symbols are $0$ and $1$. You can make room for a third symbol by mapping $0$ to $00$, $1$ to $11$ and then user $01$ as the new symbol.

Comment: @AndrejBauer and then use the same claim?

Comment: You tell me. Do you see what to do?